# Save ColdFusion Form data in Serialized JSON

Tags: json, forms, coldfusion

On the submit of my ColdFusion form I want to save the values entered into the inputs into Serialized JSON.

Below is an example I was provided from a previous question. The code below is in my action.cfm page that is set as the action page of my form.

```
<cfset formCopy = Duplicate(form)>
<!--- We have to duplicate the struct so that we can safely modify a copy without affecting the original --->
<cfset DeleteItems = "fieldnames,gobtn">
<cfloop list="#deleteItems#" index="df">
  <cfset formCopy = StructDelete(formCopy,df)>
</cfloop>

<cfset ForDBInsert = SerializeJSON(formCopy)>
<!--- ForDBInsert now contains a JSON serialized copy of your data. You can insert it into
  the database as such, and call it back later. --->
```

If I strip everything out and just leave the duplicate(form) my page still errors.

**QUESTION: Do I need to reference my form by name or just "form"?**

Comment: Are you checking for the existence of the `form` scope first? There are conditions under which it doesn't exist.

Comment: It errors with what error?

Comment: *RE: ..Do I need to reference my form by name or just "form"* No. Form names are a client side concept.  The CF server does not know anything about that. `FORM` is the name of a system scope, so it is *always* called `FORM`. It contains any values submitted to the server via POST.

Answer (score 4):

> > my page still errors.

That does not tell us much. You need to post the actual error message. However, I suspect it is because you are using [`StructDelete`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f07.html) incorrectly. `StructDelete` returns a `boolean` value, not a structure. By saving the result to "formCopy", you are overwriting the structure with a simple boolean. The next time you pass it into `StructDelete`, an error occurs, because "formCopy" is no longer a structure.